# How to update StateFullWidget from stateLessWidget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I wanted to update the `evaluateAnswer` bool and rebuild the `QuestionsList`(stateful) widget with new value when the `SubmitExamButton`(which is a stateless widget) button is pressed. But it always builds it with the `false` value which I initialized the variable with.I've tried making `Body` stateful widget with `SubmitExamButton` looking  like this:

```
SubmitExamButton(
    onPress: () {
       setState(() {
           evaluateAnswer = true;
       });
    },
),
```

Body.dart

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool evaluateAnswer = false;
    return Stack(

      children: [
        Padding(
          child: QuestionsList(
            evaluate: evaluateAnswer,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
            width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
            child: SubmitExamButton(
                onPress: () {
                  evaluateAnswer = true;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the code above is a simplified version

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your evaluateAnswer out into the member variables of a State class associated with a StatefulWidget.  Then, when you setState anywhere in that build() in the State class, the Stateful widget will rebuild.  Sticking data as the member data of a Stateless widget does not get changes noticed by the re-build mechanism.

Comment: I don't really get it...can you please illustrate it with some code or give me links where I can read more about it

Comment: Most of the "Stateless vs Stateful Widget" tutorials talk about this issue precisely.  Do a google video search for that subject.